# Pass DBID value twice in single request

Tags: jmeter, counter, performance-testing

I need to pass the DBID value two times in the single request, I have tried placing _counter function twice, but it is updating the counter value every time when it is hitting

```
 <v13:taskIdentifier>${__evalVar(taskcounter)}</v13:taskIdentifier> 
    <v13:databaseId>${__evalVar(dbid_${__counter(TRUE,)})}</v13:databaseId>
       </v12:uniqueTaskIdentifier>
       <v14:executionTime>
          <v15:value>${__time(YYYY-MM-dd)}T13:00:00</v15:value>
       </v14:executionTime>
       <v14:resourceLocation>
       <v16:identifierLocation>
       <v17:type>Unique Task Identifier</v17:type>
        <v17:identifier>${__evalVar(dbid_${__counter(TRUE,)})}${__evalVar(taskcounter)}</v17:identifier>
```

Is there any other option to get the same counter value second  time ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you save the value in [User Parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) which will be a child of the request

> allows you to specify a series of values for any User Variable. For each thread, the variable will be assigned one of the values from the series in sequence. If there are more threads than values, the values get re-used.

Define parameter value as `${__counter(TRUE,)}` and for example name `c`

Then use in XML `${c}` instead

```
<v13:taskIdentifier>${__evalVar(taskcounter)}</v13:taskIdentifier> 
<v13:databaseId>${__evalVar(dbid_${c})}</v13:databaseId>
   </v12:uniqueTaskIdentifier>
   <v14:executionTime>
      <v15:value>${__time(YYYY-MM-dd)}T13:00:00</v15:value>
   </v14:executionTime>
   <v14:resourceLocation>
   <v16:identifierLocation>
   <v17:type>Unique Task Identifier</v17:type>
    <v17:identifier>${__evalVar(dbid_${c})}${__evalVar(taskcounter)}</v17:identifier>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter%5C) **generates an incremented value each time it's being called**

The options are in:

1. Switch to [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) configuration element
2. Amend your current setup as follows:

   - 1st occurrence: `${__evalVar(dbid_${__counter(TRUE,dbid)})}`

     this will store the generated counter number into `${dbid}` JMeter Variable
   - 2nd, 3rd, etc. occurrences: `${__evalVar(dbid_${dbid})}`

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)

Comment: Using 2nd option working fine but ${dbid} value is not resetting its value on each iteration, lets say in 1st iteration we got 4 values, in 2nd iteration it should start with 1st value, but its getting value as 5. Can you help any setting to reset counter for each iteration ?